# Making a query to sort albums by genre problem

Tags: mysql

So I have 3 tables, "music", "genres", and "music_genres", music being a table of albums, genres being a table of genres, and music_genres being a table of links between the two tables (each row has a link to music and genres).

Now I'm trying to take an input set of genres that I want to filter my results by when I select all of the music.  I basically want to say if the genre_id is IN() a predefined array that I have of id's, but only show that entry from the music table if it has one entry from the music_genres table linking it to one of the specified genre_ids..

Any thoughts?

Comment: What problem are you having? and please go and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Please start using this site correctly -- you've asked several questions, but not accepted any answers or provided any comments on those answers indicating why. If you continue to ask questions without accepting any answers or interacting, we will stop answering you altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    music.*
FROM
    music
INNER JOIN
    music_genres
ON
    music.id = music_genres.music_id
WHERE
    music_genres.genre_id IN (1,2,3)
```

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY` clause if you don't want duplicate results for music in multiple genres.

Comment: Not that im complaining, but doesn't the title of the question include something about sorting?

Comment: `ORDER BY genre_id`. His question only asked about filtering by genre, that's probably what he meant in the title.